# Amplify CLI not creating Cognito User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm trying to create an iOS app and I've been having some problems. I'm using services from AWS and been using Amplify CLI to create the back end resources. After running through the Authorization documentation (ie amplify add auth) it appears that everything works in the console, and my awsconfiguration.json file is updated.

I went to look at the resources on the back end, however, and I found that the user pool and identity pool were not created.

At this point I've attempted to create an app a few times and I'm wondering if I maybe have an old configuration file cached that's still being referenced? Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Also i would post some code on this but there are no errors thrown.

Comment: Did you look a other AWS Regions as well?

Comment: Do you mean did I try to amplify configure in a different region?

Comment: @rolandforbes Did any of the answers work out for you? if not, did you ever get find a working solution?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. I followed a tutorial and everything worked fine; users could signup and login. However, when I tried to access the services in the AWS Console I could not find anything that was initialized via Amplify. Sooooo, after scouring the internet I realized that this command:

> $ amplify auth console

directs you to the User Pool that was created for your app through Amplify. 
Once I did ran that command I was able to access all the services that were created through the Amplify CLI for my app.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I switched to another region and pushed the auth module by itself (previously I had tried pushing both the auth and hosting modules at once).

To reiterate, I added the hosting resource and pushed it.

Added the auth resource and pushed it.

Just followed the exact instructions given in the AWS Amplify React & React Native [Getting Started Tutorial](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Jose Virella, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

after you run `amplify add auth`, you need to run `amplify push` to create your resources in AWS.